# ZF2 Filtering Select for setting other than empty option

Tags: php, zend-framework, select, filter, zend-framework2

my destination is to filter if a select box has a choice other than empty option.
If I set the Filter 'required' to true I get error in every case that the select box doesn't has to be empty. 
By setting the 'required' to false I get a valid form but even if I don't make a choice in Select Element.
Is there any other way to check another selection than the empty option?

```
//class for creating a Fieldset
class FieldsetCreate extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
...
  public function getRoofProductsElement()
  {
     $element = new Select(ProductFormInterface::FIELD_ROOFPRODUCT);
     $element->setLabel('Set roof products');
     $element->setAttribute('id', ProductFormInterface::FIELD_ROOFPRODUCT);
     $element->setEmptyOption('Select...');
     $element->setValueOptions(array('1'=>'None', '2' => 'Is Roof'));
     $element->setAttribute('onchange', 'setRoofProductSelection(this);');

     return $element;
  }
...
   public function getInputFilterSpecification()
   {
     return array(
         array(
             'name' => ProductFormInterface::FIELD_TYPESELECTION,
             'required' => false,

         ),
         array(
             'name' => ProductFormInterface::FIELD_ROOFPRODUCT,
             'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                new \Zend\Validator\GreaterThan(array('min' => 0)),
             )
          ),
          array(
             'name' => ProductFormInterface::FIELD_MANUFACTURERS,
             'required' => false,
          )
       );
  }
}

//Form Factory to Set Fieldset To Form and return the form
class ProductTypeFormFactory extends ProductAbstractFormFactory 
implements FactoryInterface
{

   public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
   {
       $form = new ProductForm('productForm');
       $form->addCsrfElement();

       $service = $serviceLocator->get('Product\Service\Product');
       $form->
           add($this->createFieldsetCreate($service->fetchAllProductTypes()));
       $form->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());
       $form->setValidationGroup($this->createValidationGroup());
       return $form;
   }
}

//The Service with Method createProduct
class ProductService
   implements EventManagerAwareInterface, ProductServiceInterface
{
   public function createProduct($typeId, $manufacturerId, $isRoof, $form)
   {
      $formArray = array(
          ProductFormInterface::FIELD_TYPESELECTION => $typeId,
          ProductFormInterface::FIELD_MANUFACTURERS => $manufacturerId,
          ProductFormInterface::FIELD_ROOFPRODUCT => $isRoof

      );

      $form->setData($formArray); 
      if ($form->isValid()) {
          var_dump('VALID');
      } else {
          var_dump($form->getMessages());
      }
   }
```

Thats shortest code I can give.
Although I use the GreaterThan Validator form is valid by leaving the empty option on RoofProduct Element which is 0

Comment: Source code would help

Comment: Hope it's a bit better now

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom validator and set your logic within it. In module/YourModule/src/YourModule/Form/Validator create a class for your custom validator:

### CustomValidator.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Class CustomValidator
 *
 * filename:   CustomValidator.php
 */ 
namespace YourModule\Form\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class CustomValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    const INVALID  = 'invalid';
    const WRONG    = 'WRONG';

    protected $messageTemplates     =   array
                                    (
                                        self::INVALID  => "This is invalid."
                                        self::WRONG    => "This is wrong."
                                    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // your logic //

        return $isValid;

    }

    public function isWrong($value)
    {
        // your logic //

        return $isWrong;

    }
}
```

Then, in your forms getInputFilter(), for the particular input you're creating, add your new custom validator:

```
'validators' => array
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'name'    => 'YourModule\Form\Validator\CustomValidator',
                        'options' => array
                                     (
                                         'messages' => array
                                                       (
                                                           YourModule\Form\Validator\CustomValidator::INVALID => 'This is just invalid.',
                                                           YourModule\Form\Validator\CustomValidator::WRONG   => 'This is just wrong.',
                                                       )
                                     ),
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    ),
                ),
```

You can read up on Custom Validators [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html)